# Cardview elevation is not working with androidx artifacts

Tags: android-cardview, androidx, cardview

My card view elevation stopped working and showing shadow after I updated my android studio 3.3 and migrating my project to androidx artifacts.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="@dimen/card_margin"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
               <!--Other Code-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `app:cardElevation="10dp"` property to cardview.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="@dimen/card_margin"
    **app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_margin"**
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
           <!--Other Code-->
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to specify `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` in your   `CardView` then set  `app:cardElevation="4dp"` with approbate value

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
```